# How to log 'truncate' statement for postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, logging, ddl, truncate

I would like to log when a table is truncated. I already utilized the event triggers `pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()` and `pg_event_trigger_dropped_objects()` to log ddl activities to my 'ddl_history' table, however, I don't see `TRUNCATE` is logged. Would there be away to log `TRUNCATE` operations as well?

Comment: I don't think TRUNCATE is considered DDL in Postgres. But you can write a trigger that is fired on `TRUNCATE` on the table(s) in question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the suggestion, but would this trigger only be set on a single specific table? What about if I want to set the trigger on all tables of the DB?

Answer (score 0):

`TRUNCATE` is not a DDL statement. If using a trigger is fine for you, use a regular `AFTER TRUNCATE` trigger `FOR EACH STATEMENT` rather than an event trigger.

Comment: Yes, I am thinking of creating a after truncate trigger but would this trigger can only be set on a single table? What about if I want to fire a trigger on any table of the database?

Comment: Create a lot of triggers.